# rsyslog: send logs to different file using custom template

Tags: systemd, syslog, rsyslog

So, I'm using `systemd` to send the logs to `rsyslog`, and I want to write the logs to `/var/log/app.log`.

Since it is a Java app with its own log format, I don't want to have timestamps or anything on it, just the message itself.

What I have so far is this:

```
[Unit]
Description=My App
After=network-online.target
Wants=network-online.target

[Service]
Type=simple
StandardOutput=syslog
StandardError=syslog
SyslogIdentifier=myapp
ExecStart=/usr/bin/java -jar /opt/app.jar
Restart=on-failure

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

And then I have thet `/etc/rsyslog.d/myapp.conf` file:

```
template(name="clean" type="string" string="%msg:2:$:drop-last-lf%\n")

if $programname == 'myapp' then action(type="omfile" file="/var/log/app.log" template="clean")
& stop
```

If I understand this correctly, if the program name is `myapp`, it should use the `clean` template and save the logs to `/var/log/app.log` and then stop.

That works, except that it also sends the logs to `/var/log/syslog`.

How can I prevent it to save these logs to syslog too?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The issue was that the default config file was called `50-defaults.conf`, so it was processed first...

That means that logs were being sent to `/var/log/syslog` as per defaults config, and then it goes through my config file, which does the stop, but it didn't matter because there was nothing after it.

Renaming it to `10-myapp.conf` fixes the issue.